# how does the bootstrap 4 breadcrumb's style work when hover the mouse

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I don't know how this breadcrumb is working because has two lines exactly the same... I read that css will take the last one, but when I put my mouse over, it's taking the first one

```
.breadcrumbpers-item + .breadcrumbpers-item:hover::before {
  text-decoration: underline; /*this apply to text*/
  color: #F70B27;  /*this applies to ">"*/
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4a947;  /*this applies to ">"*/
}
```

and Also this code adds the color to the ">" element and not to the text. 
It happens the same with `border-bottom: 1px solid #d4a947;` I want that the place of the text has that caracteristic but it adds the *border bottom* to the place of the ">"

Here is the html

```
<nav aria-label="breadcrumbpers">
      <ol class="breadcrumbpers">
        <li class="breadcrumbpers-item"><a class="white-text" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="breadcrumbpers-item"><a class="white-text" href="#">Library</a></li>
        <li class="breadcrumbpers-item active" aria-current="page">Evidencias | no aprobadas</li>
      </ol>
    </nav>
```

CSS. I took the same CSS from bootstrap and I changed the name to put it on my own css

```
.breadcrumbpers {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0.75rem 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #253e85;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.breadcrumbpers-item + .breadcrumbpers-item {
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
}

.breadcrumbpers-item + .breadcrumbpers-item::before {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  content: ">";
}

.breadcrumbpers-item + .breadcrumbpers-item:hover::before {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #F70B27;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4a947;
}

.breadcrumbpers-item + .breadcrumbpers-item:hover::before {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.breadcrumbpers-item.active {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4a947
}

a.white-text{
   color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a specificity problem... but I'm not quite sure what you're asking. The `border-bottom` does *indeed* get correctly applied for your second `>`, given your above code.

Comment: I want that the text like "library" or "evidencias no aprobadas" has the style that ">" is taking, the  `color: #F70B27;` property and the `border-bottom: 1px solid #d4a947;` property because the text is only taking the `text-decoration: underline` property